# How to avoid relative imports with no-restricted-imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

### What I want

I want to avoid the deep relative imports like `../../../`, and I want to allow only the relative import of `package.json` file, so I set up the eslint `no-restricted-imports` rule like so:

#### .eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'no-restricted-imports': [
      'error',
      {
        patterns: [
          {
            group: ['**/../../*', '!**/../../package.json'],
            message: 'Please use alias instead of deep relative imports.',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

#### The problem

The problem with this configuration is that it is taking the imports from `package.json` as well, so this is throwing error: `import * as PackageJSON from '../../../package.json';`

how can I avoid all relative imports except the `package.json` one?

Comment: Can't you add an alias for the package.json import as well?

Comment: I don't get ur point @GuillaumeBrunerie can u give me an exmaple please...